# Add user for resource using gcloud iam tools not via the user interface?

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-iam

I want to create a user via gcloud tools in terminal not using the user interface.

I can create a service account using gcloud tools like this: `gcloud iam service-accounts create my-service-account --display-name="My Service Account"` and give it permissions like this `gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding project-name --member="serviceAccount:my-service-account@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com" --role="roles/editor"`

I can't find the way to do this for a user instead of a service account. The closest I could find was to run: `gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding my-project --member="user:person@gmail.com" --role="roles/editor"` which results in the error `ERROR: Policy modification failed` because the user does not exist. If I create the user manually in the user interface then adding roles works.

How do I create the user via `gcloud`? This is what it looks like in the user interface..

[image]
[image]

Comment: The loosest answer is that you can't create a user using gcloud.  Users do NOT belong to GCP ... the users are Google Accounts.  So the answer to your question changes to asking the question "How do I create a user Google Account?"  The answer to that depends on whether you are using nothing, Cloud Identity or Google Worspace as your source of users today/

Comment: @Kolban please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Add Button in the permissions pages (IAM) does *not* result in the creation of a new user (i.e. it does not ADD a user).  Instead, what the *add* means is that we are *adding* permissions to the authority of the user.  Clicking `add` allows us to name an *existing* identity and also the role we wish to add to the user.

The equivalent `gcloud` command would be `gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding` that is currently documented in the GCP documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/add-iam-policy-binding).

Answer (score 2):

Turns out `gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding my-project --member="user:person@gmail.com" --role="roles/editor"` does 'add' the user.

Re: Kolban's comment. There might be a misunderstanding since I don't want to create a gmail user I just want to do the equivalent of adding them (+ADD button above) and type into the "new principals" textbox and add a role. Above code works.

Comment: I guess I'm not following.  Are you wanting to create a user where a user doesn't exist already?  For example, if there is no such user as "d3f2@gmail.com" then you want to create that user and THEN authorize that user to have a given GCP role?   Or ... does the user already exist and you want to authorize the user for a role?

Comment: the user has created a gmail account via gmail.com so in that sense they exist but they have no previous roles assigned in GCP and they are a user outside my organisation

Comment: Thanks for the response.  You might want to update the question.  It comes across as a desire to create a user identity as opposed to assigning permissions to an existing user identity.

Comment: Can someone else weigh in with a third opinion if i should update the question? I thought adding the screenshots makes it clear i want to do what the UI does when you click the 'add' button with the avatar icon and afaik that does not create a user identity.

Comment: When you click the Add button, you specify a principal (an identity) and a role and then that role is associated with the principal.  I think this is what you already discovered to be the same as running the command "gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding project-name".  The identity specified with "--member" should already exist.  The "add" command in the console doesn't create a new identity .. it adds a role to an existing identity.

Comment: If you post a short summary I can mark it as answer for the points.

Comment: Happy to my friend but only if it legitamtely answers your puzzle.  Hope it helped.